# Saber si una imagen existe o no se cargo correctamente

Tags: javascript

Como podria saber cuando una imagen exista o se cargo en el navegador con `javascript` y `Jquery`, seria un ejemplo como este;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto para cargar una imagen alternativa en caso de que la imagen no exista, algo como `IMAGE NOT FOUND`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He logrado solucionar esto de la siguiente manera;

Un sencillo script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /**
     * Determinar si una imagen existe por la propiedad naturalHeight
     * la cual sera diferente de 0 si esta existe
     **/
    $('img').each(function(){
        if($(this)[0].naturalHeight == 0){
             $(this).attr('src','images/image_not_found.jpg');
        }
    });
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Logre dar con esta solucion a travez de la propiedad `naturalHeight` la cual debe ser diferente de 0 si la imagen existe, por muy pequeña que sea la imagen debe de tener una altura.

Quizas no sea la mejor manera pero si tienes un proyecto "grande" muchas veces `javascript` es una solución.

Answer (score 6):

Las imágenes (etiquetas `<img>`), cuando trabajas con el DOM, son objetos del tipo [HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement). Este elemento puede hacer uso de los eventos "onerror" y "onload":

```js
const imgs=Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img'));
imgs.forEach(i => i.addEventListener('error',event => {
  console.log('Falló la carga de', event.target.src);
  })
);
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/>
<img src="http://falla.noexisto.doh"/>
```

El problema aquí sería que el javascript que añade los listeners se pueda cargar más tarde que las imágenes, con lo que estos errores no se detectarían, pero es un método útil cuando estás inyectando imágenes en el DOM tras la carga de la página.

Comment: Me parece bastante interesante tu ejemplo ya que haces uso de vanilla `javascript`

Answer (score 2):

Me parece muy interesante tu solución. Otra manera de hacer sería aprovechar el evento **onerror**. Lanzado sobre una imagen se dispararía cuando el enlace devolviese un error de ruta.

**JS**

```
function reemplaza_imagen(imagen) {
    imagen.onerror = "";
    imagen.src = "/imagenes/imagen_error_carga.png";
    return true;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="image.png" onerror="reemplaza_imagen(this);"/>
```

Comment: Esa fue mi primera opción pero jamas logre hacerlo funcionar :(

Comment: Pues tienes razón. No funciona. Esta deprecada desde la versión 1.8 de Jquery y borrada desde la 3.0. Pero estoy seguro de que tiene que haber algo parecido, a ver si luego tengo un rato y lo miro con más detenimiento.

Comment: Encontré esta solución con JS puro y a través de un evento **onerror** lanzado desde HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/oLqfxjoz/ Aun así estoy seguro de que tiene que haber una alternativa desde Jquery al evento .error().

Answer (score 2):

Yo sé que llego tarde, sin embargo tengo algo mucho más sencillo que he implementado hace poco en un proyecto personal.

En la etiqueta **img** puedes colocar el evento **onerror** y agregarle la imagen, sin tener que recurrir a escribir más código en un archivo js.

```
<img src="/ruta/imagen.png" onerror="this.src='/ruta/respaldo.png'"/>
```

No tienes que declarar ninguna función ni usar JQuery, el **this** hace referencia a la etiqueta **img**, y al ser un objeto, posee el evento **onerror**.

Answer (score 1):

Con el evento `error` del DOM puedes manejar esto.

```
ElementoImg.addEventListener('error', e => {
 ElementoImg.src = '/404.jpg' //Esto es una imagen de respaldo que se supone estás seguro de que existe
})
```

En la etiqueta *img* puedes agregar el atributo `onerror = "function()"` de igual manera.

```html
<img src="img/mi-imagen.jpg" onerror="myfunction()">
```

Esta última opción no me sirvió cuando incrustaba código html con javascript. Agregar el evento como en el primer ejemplo luego de incrustar el html me funcionó.

Comment: Ok, editaré el comentario...