# Guardar imagen en LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, imagen, cache

Buen día, ya puedo guardar imágenes en el localstorage, pero lo que quiero es que cuando borro cache me cargue una imagen predeterminada y no me deje vació el div desde cada reinicio de cache.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var img = new Image();
img.src = localStorage.theImage;

$('.imagearea').html(img);

$("body").on("change",".classhere",function(){

  var fileInput = $(this)[0];
  var file = fileInput.files[0]; 

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {       
       
       var img = new Image();

       img.src = reader.result;
       localStorage.theImage = reader.result; 
       $(".imagearea").html(img);
   }

   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
});
```

```html
<input class="classhere" type="file" id="img" name="img">
<div class="imagearea"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hace relativamente poco tuve una cuestionante similar la cual puedes ver aca [Saber si una imagen existe o no se cargo correctamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/203106/saber-si-una-imagen-existe-o-no-se-cargo-correctamente)

Esto consiste en analizar los elementos `img` (se puede indicar un elemento en particular con el selector);

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /**
     * Determinar si una imagen existe por la propiedad naturalHeight
     * la cual sera diferente de 0 si esta existe
     **/
    $('img').each(function(){
        if($(this)[0].naturalHeight == 0){
             $(this).attr('src','images/image_not_found.jpg');
        }
    });
});
```

Con la propiedad `naturalHeight` sabras si la imagen posee dimensiones, una imagen por pequeña que sea tendra dimensiones, solo si y solo si no se carga una imagen no tendra `naturalHeight`.